# Objective-C Cannot Initialize a Variable of Type CFStringRef in .mm extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

I'm importing contacts from iPhone contacts in my class and then I made the extension of my file to a c++ (because I need to use a library that requires it to be .mm) and then an error occurred.

code: `CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j);`

error: `cannot initialize a variable of type 'CFStringRef' (aka'const__CFString*') with an rvalue of type CFTypeRef (aka 'const void *')`

I'm pretty much lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I randomly put `(CFStringRef)` after the **=** sign and it fixed the error. It seems that c++ compiler doesn't want automatic casting.

This did the trick:

```
CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = (CFStringRef) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j);
```